# What is and how to open a .xsig file extension?

Tags: filesystems

I have received a .xsig document, that I can read in plain text. Is there any way of visualize the document with an application?

Answer (score 1):

It should be a [XML Signature doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature)

[Here](http://www.filetypeadvisor.com/extension/xsig) they are suggesting to use XMLspy

Answer (score 0):

You have an application called eCofirma. It has ben developed by the Spanish Gov and allows for validating signature an download original file.

Comment: According to the web site "The eCoFirma application enables electronic signing of documents in XAdES format in a simple and fast way."  This app does not seem to answer the question.